# How to verify if a vector in three space lies on another vector?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I can find the intersection points of graphs when asked, but I am unsure what to do when I must "verify if the curve lies on the surface".

> Verify that the curve $r(t)$ lies on the given
>   surface. Give the name of the surface:
>
> $r(t) = (0,\;2\text{cos}(t),\;3\text{sin}(t))$
>
> $x^2 + y^2/4 + z^2/9 = 1$

Appreciate the help

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

The points $(x,y,z)$ of the curve are such that there exist $t$ satisfying

$$x=0, y=2\cos(t), y=3\sin(t)$$

the points $ (x,y,z)$ of the surface must satisfy
$$x^2+y^2/4+z^2/9=\color{red}{1}$$

the curve lies in the surface is each point of the curve is in the surface.

but if we replace, we find that

$$0^2+(2\cos(t))^2/4+(3\sin(t))^2/9=\color{red}1$$

done.

Answer (score 0):

The surface is called an *ellipsoid*.

You can check that $x=0, y=2\cos t,z=3\sin t$ satisfies $x^2+\dfrac{y^2}4+\dfrac {z^2}9=0^2+\dfrac{4\cos^2t}4+\dfrac {9\sin^2t}9=\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1$.

Thus the curve lies on the surface.